# What is the metal bit in the front of this propeller spinner?

Tags: propeller, piston-engine, feature-identification

What is that grey spirally bit in front of the propeller mounted on this Shvetsov ASh-62 radial engine?

[image]

Comment: The aircraft it's connected to seems to be a [Lisunov LI-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisunov_Li-2), a licensed version of the DC-3 built by Russia. This may be the only flying example of the aircraft.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It is a fitting for a [Hucks Starter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hucks_starter).

Photos from [Vintage Wings Canada](http://www.vintagewings.ca/VintageNews/Stories/tabid/116/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/381/language/en-CA/The-Moment--First-Hucks-Start-in-70-Years.aspx)

[image]
[image]

Comment: I saw the first photo and assumed the starter shaft was just connected to some typical-looking airport equipment. The second photo was quite the surprise,.

Comment: Here I was hoping it was a bottle opener... :/

Comment: I'm getting a picture of somebody forgetting to chock the aircraft wheels, and the starter truck crashing into something while reversing out of the way at top speed :)

Comment: @FreeMan It's a Russian engine. The vodka is in the fuel tank, not in the nose cone.

Comment: Both the airplane and the truck are beautiful.  Just beautiful.

Comment: I had a 1964 Datsun pickup that had a fitting like that -- it fit the truck's jack handle, but it was in fact for starting the engine.  Actually used it once...